# Retrieving videos via the YouTube API returns nothing

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve some YouTube videos, I'm using a script from http://www.w3resource.com/API/youtube/tutorial.php

I have set my referrer up as

> mydomain.com/

at https://console.developers.google.com/project

The form displays, but as soon as I search for something nothing gets returned just a blank page.

Should the referrer be setup as the full path to the script?

```
    <?php
if ($_GET['q'] && $_GET['maxResults']) {
  // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
  require_once ('Google_Client.php');
  require_once ('Google_YouTubeService.php');

  /* Set $DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
  Google APIs Console <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
  Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
  $DEVELOPER_KEY = '*****';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  $youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

  try {
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    ));

    $videos = '';
    $channels = '';

    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],
            $searchResult['id']['videoId']."<a href=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$searchResult['id']['videoId']." target=_blank>   Watch This Video</a>");
          break;
        case 'youtube#channel':
          $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],
            $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
          break;
       }
    }

   } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube Search</title>
<link href="//www.w3resource.com/includes/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
body{margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 50px}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="GET">
  <div>
    Search Term: <input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search Term">
  </div>
  <div>
    Max Results: <input type="number" id="maxResults" name="maxResults" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="25">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<h3>Videos</h3>
    <ul><?php echo $videos; ?></ul>
    <h3>Channels</h3>
    <ul><?php echo $channels; ?></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My API key I am getting from:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the "API Key" from? I don't see an "Access" tab in the developer's console. All the examples at https://developers.google.com/youtube show setting the Client ID, Client Secret and Scope.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my original post to show where I am getting the API key from.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow won't let me edit my answer so I'm creating a new one. The tutorial seems to go back and forth between using an OAuth client ID/secret and an API key. AFAIK, you need a client ID/secret to access information that you would need to log in to YouTube for. You use an API key to access public information. In the case of the sample you're using, it just lists public information so it uses an API key.

To create an API key, click on the Create New Key button under Public API Access, select Server Key and enter the IP address of your web server. That gives you an API key which you set as the DEVELOPER_KEY in your script. I followed that procedure and the sample script works fine.